# Change props from Chrome Developer Tool?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to set `enableSelectAll` to `true` for a Material-UI TableHeader. This component is stateless (or at least there is no state displayed in the React Chrome (50) Developer Tool). If I try to edit one of the props, pressing enter does nothing. Perhaps this is by design as I believe props aren't meant to be modified. But I'd like to enable/disable that property nonetheless. Is there a way to do this from within the developer tools?

Comment: Are you using React Chrome Dev Tools? https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/01/02/react-chrome-developer-tools.html

Comment: @JohnWilliamDomingo Yes. I had previously written "Chrome Developer Tool" and have since made an edit.

Comment: TableHeader may be stateless but it extends the React Component so it definitely should have a props property. See https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/Table/TableHeader.js

Comment: I am also unable to edit my props. Have you tried this before with state?

Comment: I was able to edit Table.state.allRowsSelected and the UI responded (pretty nice).

Comment: Oh very nice. I'm also curious now what makes certain properties dynamic in the dev tools.

Comment: props are passed from the parent, and setting a value in props on a child element will just get the value of props overwritten by the parent again. You should be able to define a state in it though without issues.

Answer (score -1):

If you just set property, it would be overwritten on the next tree update, so it's a bad idea.

I recommend moving such properties into the state and set it with this.setState().